# Moving text to the left of images or text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move the text 'Next Steps' to the right of the text similar to the example below. I have the code below but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or of it's the default spacing of the form builder I'm using but I'm sure there's a way to bypass it

[Here's what I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyQW1.png)

[I want the 'Next Steps' to be where the 'You May Be Wondering' is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr4t6.jpg)

---

```html
<h1 class='next-steps'> Next Steps</h1>
<h1 class='experience'>Your Wedding Experience <br> Begins Here</h1>


<style>

h1.next-steps {
color: #1F1F1F;
font-size: 100px;
font-weight:500;
-ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
-webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
transform: rotate(180deg);
position: absolute;
padding-left: -40;!important;

}

h1.experience {
color: white;
font-size: 48px;
font-weight:500;
text-align: center;
position: relative;

}

<!--DEVICE RESPONSIVE--!>

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

h1.next-steps {
font-size: 9vw;
}

h1.experience {
font-size: 8vw;
}

}

<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `position: relative;` or `position: absolute;`. Then position the node with top, right, bottom, and/or left css property. I think using relative is the way to go. If you run into layering problems, use `z-index` to fix that